# PHP5 SOAP : how to keep an instance?

Tags: php, soap, instance

I'm playing around with SOAP and PHP. But I can't figure it out why the returned object seems not to keep the instance. Let me show you first the example code and then I will explain:

**client.php :**

```
  $client = new SoapClient("http://myhost/remote.wsdl");
  try {
    if($client->login("root","toor")) {
        echo $client->getTotal()."\n";
    }
  } catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    echo $exception;
  }
```

**server.php :**

```
class Remote {
  private $auth = false;

  public function login($user, $pass) {
    if($user == "root" && $pass == "toor") {
        $this->auth = true;
        return true;
    } else throw new SoapFault("Server","Access Denied to '$user'.");
  }

  public function getTotal() {
    if($this->auth) {
        return rand(1000,9999);
    } else throw new SoapFault("Server","Error: Not Authorized.");
  }
}

$server = new SoapServer("remote.wsdl");
$server->setClass("Remote");
$server->handle();
```

I'm able to "login" so the returned value from **$client->login** is *true*.
But, when I call **$client->getTotal**, **$this->auth** is *false* (and thus the error is raised).

What do I need to do in order to keep the value I set previously?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! the solution was here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapserver.setpersistence.php

This is the result:

```
session_start(); //Important
$server = new SoapServer("remote.wsdl");
$server->setClass("Remote");
$server->setPersistence(SOAP_PERSISTENCE_SESSION); 
$server->handle();
```

And that's it!